# Which model should I use for determinants of NPLs

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, generalized-moments, dynamic-regression

I am working on a subject called The determinants of NPLs in a country (NPL = non performing loans).

My data is a dynamic panel data of 15 years and i got my data yearly.
The dependent variable is npl ratio and i have 8 independent variables.

I have run tests on stata that i will mention below

- The vif test showed no multicollinearity issues
- Breusch pagan showed heteroscedasticity
- Autocorrelation showed first order correlation
- Finally , the Hausman test to whether proceed with fixed or random effects showed a p value of 0,09.

My questions are:

1. Should I do any other tests ?
2. And what should I use for my estimations ? Some suggested Arellano bond but doesn't the Hausman test say that I dont have endogeneity problems ?

I am really confused and I hope i made my questions clear.
Thank you everyone in advance